# How to disable clicking off website disclaimer

Tags: css, popup

This is becoming very frustrating now! I have the Disclaimer plugin EMC2 Pop-Up Disclaimer.

On my site it works fine, (Site is under development URL until I can fix this) except for it allows the user to click anywhere off the side of the disclaimer and this closes it, instead of the disclaimer making then click Accept or Decline.

I managed to fix this issue for Chrome users by adding:

```
.fancybox-opened {
z-index: 8030;
pointer-events: all !important;
}

.fancybox-lock .fancybox-overlay {
pointer-events: none;

}
```

I know it is a lazy CSS fix but it seems to be the only thing that got me there.

But this CSS does not hold for IE/windows.

I just need to have it so that the user cant click off the disclaimer (in the lightbox).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

prevent from right click

Answer (score 0):

If you are using fancybox then maybe you have 'closeClick' option set to true and then it closes the box on click. Also it matters which version of fancybox you are using.
If you are using v1.3 to prevent the close effect add this to the options

```
hideOnOverlayClick:false,
hideOnContentClick:false
```

For v2

```
helpers : { 
  overlay : {closeClick: false}
}
```